# Selecting continuous pull type solenoid

Tags: solenoid, watts, component-selection

I own a Rail track master and it needs two pull type continuous solenoids. The age of this machine is from the 1950's and both of the previous solenoids were unidentifiable. These solenoids operate the systems' sand boxes for dispersing sand on the track for the machine gain traction.

I need help with calculating/selecting the right type of solenoid. The specs that I have are:

- 12 volt system,
- pull in solenoid,
- 1-3 inches stroke,
- continuous cycle (energized by momentary electrical switch),
- Cylindrical shape solenoid body,
- watts needed unknown,
- 10-12 gauge wire will be used for install.

Comment: What you really need to know is the force required to activate the mechanism. Can you rig up something with a spring scale to determine how much tension the solenoid needs to apply to its mechanical connection to the rest of the system? Pay attention to how the force varies along the stroke length.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the old solenoids, connect one to the 12v battery, through an amp meter, and measure the current.  Do the same with the other one and use the higher value to select its replacement.  Obviously, it must also meet the mechanical requirements.

If you don't have the old solenoids, then you will have to guess.  I would recommend starting with a 12v 5A.  Good luck.